# COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE WHEN IN ('A','B')

Tags: mysql

Hi Everyone wondered if anyone could help with the below:

```
SELECT
  HOST_ORDER_NO,
  EARLIEST_PICK_DATE,
  PRODUCT_NO,
  PRODUCT_NUM_PARTS,
  PRODUCT_WHS_LOCATION,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(CASE 
   WHEN LEFT(PRODUCT_WHS_LOCATION,1) IN ('A','B','C','K','M','N') THEN 'BULK'
   WHEN LEFT(PRODUCT_WHS_LOCATION,1) IN ('D','E','F') THEN 'TEN'
   WHEN LEFT(PRODUCT_WHS_LOCATION,1) IN ('G','H','I','J','L') THEN 'TENSMALL'
   ELSE 'SIP' END) AS 'ZONE',
  MAX(COLLATION_INDICATOR),
  COLLATION_GROUP_ID,
  CASE WHEN COUNT(HOST_ORDER_NO)=1 THEN 'SingleOrder' ELSE 'MultiItem' END AS 'OrderType',
  COUNT(*) AS 'ItemsInOrder',
  YEARWEEK
FROM wk19
  WHERE YearWeek = '201717'
  GROUP BY HOST_ORDER_NO
  HAVING OrderType = 'MultiItem'
  ORDER BY HOST_ORDER_NO, COLLATION_GROUP_ID, MAX(COLLATION_INDICATOR);
```

My error is in the case statment I want to be able to see how many different areas the orders are coming from with in the warehouse. The rest of the statement works fine, but if I need to breck it down more I can do.

Comment: Can you add the db schema's ? And why are your column names in full caps?

Comment: Its from a very old table when the DB admin was learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `case` *expression* is just missing parentheses.  No paren is needed after `distinct`, so:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN LEFT(PRODUCT_WHS_LOCATION,1) IN ('A','B','C','K','M','N') THEN 'BULK'
                    WHEN LEFT(PRODUCT_WHS_LOCATION,1) IN ('D','E','F') THEN 'TEN'
                    WHEN LEFT(PRODUCT_WHS_LOCATION,1) IN ('G','H','I','J','L') THEN 'TENSMALL'
                     ELSE 'SIP'
               END) AS ZONE,
```

A word of advice:  Only use single quotes for strings and dates.  Don't use them for column aliases.